# Facebook Graph API group feed

Tags: facebook-api

Можно ли получать посты из своей группы в Facebook через Graph API без business verification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет нельзя, единственный вариант пройти проверку приложения в Facebook и затем добавить данное приложение себе в группу чтоб получать данные из нее.